# PrimeFaces 4.0 themes

Tags: maven, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm in trouble in my primefaces 4.0 setup, I have the following settings in my pom.xml:

But nothing works, I need to improve some more code, taken a look in this forum but did not solve my problems.

Comment: where is your pom file ???

Comment: Can you try to explain us your trouble in a more cleaner way?